# My partial view is not being set up correctly

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an application done in ASP.NET MVC and I am having an issue where my partial view is not being rendered after my form is submitted. What it does is that it reloads the entire page.

**Here is my Model:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public List<User> User = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

**Here is my View:**

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }
    @model Portfolio.Models.HomeViewModel

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FooForm",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
      HttpMethod = "get",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      UpdateTargetId = "FooView"
    }))
  {
    <button type:"submit" value:"Refresh/>

  }
@Html.Partial("_FooView", Model)

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () { $("#FooForm").submit(); }, 5000);
  };
</script>
```

Here is my partial view:

```
@model Portfolio.Models.HomeViewModel
<div id="FooView">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.User.Count; i++)
        {
            <form>
                <div id="Name">@Model.User[i].Name</div>
                <div id="Email">@Model.User[i].Email</div>
                <div id="Date">@Model.User[i].Date</div>
            </form>
            <div>---------------------
        </div>
        }    
    </div>
```

**Finally, here is my Controller:**

```
using Portfolio.Models;
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Portfolio.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
        Timer Timer = new Timer();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            model.User.Add(new User() { Name = "A", Email = "a@email.com", Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) });
            model.User.Add(new User() { Name = "B", Email = "b@email.com", Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2) });
            model.User.Add(new User() { Name = "C", Email = "c@email.com", Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3) });

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
               return PartialView("_FooView", model);
            }
            return View(model)
        }            
    }
}
```

Can someone see why my Index Action is return the entire view and not the partial view upon Ajax request? Am I not setting my Ajax form properly? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code wont even compile. but if your redirecting, then you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not redirecting. I am trying to set up the code to where it loads a partial view after a time span have passed (3 seconds as an example)

Comment: Its hard to understand what your trying to achieve here or what your problem is. Your `Ajax.BeginForm` calls a method named `FooForm` but you have not shown that. The `Index()` method you have shown does not compile (there is no `return` statement for the case where its not ajax)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the index.

Comment: But what is the `FooForm()` method that your `Ajax.BeginForm` is calling?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I must have copied it wrong before. I fixed it now to how I have it in my IDE. One issue I am seeing though is the facet that my set timeout is not being fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165005/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mmangual83).

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current form. You need to show the contents of the "FooForm" action that is processing the form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, your script does not submit your form because your form does not have an `id` attribute with a value of `FooForm`. Your `Ajax.BeginForm()` code does not add an `id` attribute (and is in fact calling a method in your controller named `FooForm()`. Assuming you really want to call the `Index()` method in your script then change the `BeginForm` code to

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", null, new AjaxOptions(....), new { id = "FooForm" }))
```

which will generate `<form .... id="FooForm" >`

Then if your actually not hitting the code in the `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` that returns the `PartialView`, it means your making a normal submit which means that you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in the view (or its not loading correctly or is loaded in the wrong order)

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing double-quote on this line after Refresh: `<button type:"submit" value:"Refresh/>`

Comment: fixed it but my page still reloads entirely. Not sure why.

Comment: Did you put a break point on "return PartialView" to see if it ever gets fired? Are you thinking that your "setTimeout" function will make an ajax request? I think that's just going to do a normal submit. Its not clear what you are trying to do here.